# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'link'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to make a discord.py bot command that sends random dog fact and image but i've got this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'link'
```

Here's the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def dog(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animal/dog')
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) 

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'random dog fact') 
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no key in the JSON response called `"link"`. Use `"fact"` instead for the dog fact, and `"image"` for the random dog image.

Also, instead of this code block:

```
response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animal/dog')
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

you can use

```
json_data = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animal/dog').json()
```

using Requests' built-in [`json()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method.

Comment: i did everything like you said but i've got another error "Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body" i think something is wrong with the api

Comment: The API is working fine for me. Perhaps you've hit it too many times and you've been banned for a certain amount of time.